# htaccess set environment variable using another environment variable

Tags: .htaccess, variables, environment-variables

I can't find an answer for my question.

Can I set an environment variable using another environment variable ?

Example:

```
SetEnv msg_1 "First message"
SetEnv msg_2 "%{ENV:msg_1} Second message"
```

To be clear, I don't want to use `%{ENV:msg_1}%{ENV:msg_2}`.

I wan't to use `%{ENV:msg_2}`.

Is that possible, cause doesn't seems to work to me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> SetEnv msg_2 "%{ENV:msg_1} Second message"
> ```

You will need to use mod_rewrite (or `SetEnvIf` - See [@anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65725173/369434)) instead in order to set an environment variable using the value of another env var. Unfortunately, `SetEnv` (mod_env) and `SetEnvIf` (mod_setenvif) do not expand the value of env vars using the syntax `%{ENV:varname}` in the resulting expression, it is simply seen as literal text.

However, if you use mod_rewrite then you can't use `SetEnv` to set your initial env var since it is processed too late. You will need to use either `SetEnvIf` or mod_rewrite to set the initial env var.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine on

SetEnvIf ^ ^ "msg_1=First message"

RewriteRule ^ - "[E=msg_2:%{ENV:msg_1} Second message]"
```

Note the strategically placed double quotes because the value argument contains spaces.

- `SetEnvIf` - the entire `name=value` pair in the `SetEnvIf` directive must be surrounded in double quotes (not the value).
- `RewriteRule` - the entire *flags* argument needs to be surrounded in double quotes (not the value).

This does allow you a bit more flexibility than `SetEnvIf`, since you can reference any number of env vars in the *value* portion if you need to.

Comment: I like this `^ ^` ++

Answer (score 5):

It is an interesting problem. `SetEnv` has very limited feature and scope.

You can use [`SetEnvIf`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) here.

```sh
# set msg_1
SetEnvIf Host ^ "msg_1=First message"

# set msg_2 using msg_1
SetEnvIf msg_1 "(.*)" "msg_2=$1 Second message"
```

`$1` is value we are capturing in group #1 which is `(.*)` (everything).

Comment: Ah yes, I'd overlooked that you can reference another env var in the `SetEnvIf` directive itself. ++